# React native apps too large size

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Am working on app development using react native,am getting one problem after i convert the react code into apk file,The size of the app gets too large around 60 to 70 mb even though there is only one screen in the app with two three ui components,How can i reduce the size?

Comment: 1. Use EAS Build
2. Disable third-party libraries and see if the size has changed
3. If you plan to publish on Google Play, then build aab instead of apk, this will reduce the size of the uploaded file

Comment: Thanks Dmitro for your response.... I tried your approach but it just reduce the app size to half 32 mb from 64 mb. This too is large as my app contains only single screen. Can you help me out with other solutions?

Comment: That is one downside of react.

Comment: I think that's all you can do. The size of our application is 60mb, when using aab, our users download 20mb from googleplay and 15mb from the appstore.

Comment: 20 mb just for 1 screen its too heavy then too... Any better optimistic solution  than this??